# Есть цикл с условием. Как сделать вывод работы цикла после выхода?

Tags: java

Алгоритм работы программы:

- Чтение символов;
- Перевод символов из ASCII кода;
- Вывод результата
- на экран;
- Запросить повторный ввод символов.

**Пример**

- Введите ASCII код (end для вывода результата): 150
- Введите ASCII код (end для вывода результата): 151
- Введите ASCII код (end для вывода результата): end Результат: hi
- Введите ASCII код (end для вывода результата)

Мой код

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        //Цикл будет работать, пока пользователь не введет `end`
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Введите ASCII код (end для вывода результата):");
            String input = scanner.nextLine();
            if ("end".equals(input)) {
                System.out.println("Результат:");
                break;
            }
            //TODO
            int dec = Integer.parseInt( input,8);
            int result = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(dec));
            System.out.println(Character.toString((char)result));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: В итоге программа должна работать вот так :

Comment: Функционал программы
Чтение символов;
Перевод символов из ASCII кода;
Вывод результата на экран;
Запросить повторный ввод символов.
Пример
Введите ASCII код (end для вывода результата):
150
Введите ASCII код (end для вывода результата):
151
Введите ASCII код (end для вывода результата):
end
Результат:
hi

Введите ASCII код (end для вывода результата):
...

Comment: Можете удалить комментарии и просто отредактировать вопрос? В комментариях очень бедные возможности форматирования. А что уже было испробовано? Чем `System.out.println` после цикла может не устроить?

Comment: Спасибо. Я просто еще учусь, многого не знаю ) 2 суток мучился с этим выводом))))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно так

```
class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    //Цикл будет работать, пока пользователь не введет `end`
    StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
    res.append("Результат");
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Введите ASCII код (end для вывода результата):");
        String input = scanner.nextLine();
        if ("end".equals(input)) {
            System.out.println("Результат:");
            break;
        }
        //TODO
        int dec = Integer.parseInt( input,8);
        int result = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(dec));
        res.append( Character.toString((char)result) ); 
    }

     System.out.println(res.toString());
}
}
```